# To what extent can Microsoft Project Server 2010 assist me with sharing the project plan and sharing tasks / task status

Tags: ms-project-2010

I've found it really hard to find decent materials that clearly explain what Microsoft Project Server 2010 does, everything I've discovered is drenched in Microsoft business waffle such as "Extensible and programmable platform", "Drive accountability and control with governance workflow".

What I want is a tool that will enable me to share a high level project plan with my colleagues (read only) so they can see what they are currently working on and what is coming up + a list of the tasks that are currently assigned to them with the ability to record time spent and task status.

Does Project Server 2010 allow me to do this? My organisation has Microsoft Certified Partner status therefore I already have access to this tool if I want to implement it - it's been dropped on a server and I'm currently at the juncture of deciding whether or not it's worth pursuing.

Comment: Due to site scope change, we are closing all tool recommendation questions. See http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/questions/351/we-will-be-closing-all-tool-recommendations-within-2-weeks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Microsoft Project Server 2010 will allow you to create a project plan, publish it and let your colleagues see the project schedule at a detail level or high level rollup.  Resources who are assigned to tasks can see which tasks they are assigned to and even update tasks directly through the website.

Microsoft Project Server 2010 runs off SharePoint Server 2010.  It requires 64 bit server hardware, regular maintenance and helps when you have someone who knows what they are doing not just someone with good tech skills.

Project Professional 2010 is a desktop tool and its used in conjunction with Project Server to create and publish project plans.  Most people who are project managers are familiar in some way shape or form with this tool.

Managing this tool on a day to day basis can get complicated.  If you just want to keep some basic project plans with some basic information you can do that pretty easily.  Don't get caught up in all of the high end features like Strategy, Business Intelligence and Workflow approval as those features and functionalities take much more care and feeding.

If you decide to take Project Server to the next level, I would definitely recommend engaging a local consultant to help you get set up properly.  Disclaimer- I am a Project Server consultant and I'm often called in to fix in-house project server deployments so find someone local through Microsoft Partner Point IF you really want it to work right.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is Clarizen.Their task management software (cloud based, SaaS) allows you to collaborate really easily with your team. You make a plan and list all the stages along the way. Assign tasks to each member of the team and deadlines for those tasks. Each morning, the program will tell you what urgently needs to be done that day. You can track progress and the team can communicate easily with each other using email, notes or chat. And, because it's cloud based you can access it from nay computer. Clarizen's online task management is user friendly and won't speak to you in "microsoft waffle". If you are a project manager, you should defintely have a look http://www.clarizen.com/ProjectSoftware/Features/TaskManagement.aspx and take the free tour.
Good luck with your project!